# excluding values from a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following code.. and I know it's probably all wrong, but I haven't dealt with foreach loops before.

```
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );
foreach ($last_names as $name => $last_name_id)
    $exclude = array('11196','11195','11198','11197');
    if(!in_array($name->last_name_id, $exclude)):
    print '<option value="'.$last_name_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
```

Obviously its going wrong somewhere, any help pls?

Comment: put this on your page and post the results here.
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );
print_r($last_names);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the IDs are array values, then you can also use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) to filter them:

```
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );

$exclude = array('11196','11195','11198','11197');
$last_names = array_diff($last_names, $exclude);

foreach ($last_names as $name => $last_name_id) {
    print '<option value="'.$last_name_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );
$exclude = array('11196','11195','11198','11197');
foreach ($last_names as $name => $last_name_id)
{
    if(!in_array($name->last_name_id, $exclude))
        print '<option value="'.$last_name_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

You need the braces for a multiline loop. also, move the array declaration outside the loop

Comment: This solution looks solid, although single line ifs without {} is bad practice imo.

Comment: also, $name => $last_name_id looks like you can just call $last_name_id, but since you used $name->last_name_id I assumed you intended it this way. Maybe $name is an object. I don't know.

Comment: yeah you can debate any non{} and in the end it is always bad practice I think. Just I wanted to show how he WOULD use it since his original had no braces.

Comment: This doesn't exclude the names.. they still show up in the select.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn that into...

```
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );

$last_names = array_filter($last_names, function($value) {
    return in_array($value, array('11196','11195','11198','11197'));
});

foreach ($last_names as $name => $last_name_id) {
    print '<option value="'.$last_name_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

When you get to doing your loop, you are only iterating over the set you want. This is useful for separating your business rules (dropping certain ids) and presentation (echoing the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write it a little different this isn't correct ($name isn't an object)

```
$name->last_name_id
```

Something along the lines of:

```
$last_names = regapiGetLastNames( NULL, -1 );
$exclude = array('11196','11195','11198','11197');

foreach ($last_names as $name => $last_name_id) {
    if(!in_array($last_name_id, $exclude)) print '<option value="'.$last_name_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```