# How can I exclude certain records from an XML parse?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, foreach, array-difference

I'm pulling data from an XML file using the following code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.inveroak.com/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$items = array();
$exclude = array('4419','4373');
$items = array_diff($items, $exclude);

foreach($xml as $Reader) { 
    $items[] = $Reader; 
}
usort ($items, function($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->Status,$b->Status); 
});

foreach($items as $Reader) { 
    if($Reader->Status != 'Logged Off' && $Reader->Picture != 'None')
        {
        include '/extras/reader-single.php';
        }
}

?>
```

The two lines showing $exclude and $items I've added afer seeing another post [excluding values from a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175470/excluding-values-from-a-foreach-loop) about excluding from XML, but when i load the page.. the two records that have the PINs specified, are still showing.

Is this the correct way to exclude pulling certain records from an XML file?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The four digit numbers entered are a PIN number found at Reader->PIN
After thinking, could it be that it's not making the link between the number and the Reader->PIN on the xml file?

Comment: usually you'll call a function instead of using `include` multiple times in a loop

Comment: The included file, is basically a skeleton layout for each person to be displayed. How will using a function allow me to create an HTML layout? Besides, it works fine as it is. It pulls through all records on that XML file, I just need to exclude some by entering the PINs in a list

Comment: get the pin of each record, compare it to the exclude array, if it is part of the exclude array then just `continue` the loop

Comment: Sorry to sound vague, but how exactly would I do that? I appreciate the help, but I'm very inexperienced with functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told in comments, get the pin of each record, compare it to the exclude array, if it is part of the exclude array then just continue the loop. Like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.inveroak.com/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$items = array();
$exclude = array('4419','4373');
$items = array_diff($items, $exclude);

foreach($xml as $Reader) { 
    $items[] = $Reader; 
}

usort ($items, function($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->Status,$b->Status); 
});

foreach($xml as $Reader) { 
    if($Reader->Status != 'Logged Off'
        && $Reader->Picture != 'None'
        // check if the Pin is in exclude array
        && !in_array($Reader->Pin, $exclude)
    ) { 
        include '/extras/reader-single.php';
    }   
}
```

Alternatively you may use `array_filter()`:

```
$url = 'http://www.inveroak.com/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$items = array();
$exclude = array('4419','4373');
$items = array_diff($items, $exclude);

foreach($xml as $Reader) { 
    $items[] = $Reader; 
}

$items= array_filter($items, function($Reader) use ($exclude) {
    if($Reader->Status == 'Logged Off'
       || $Reader->Picture == 'None'
       || in_array($Reader->Pin, $exclude)
    ) { 
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
});

usort ($items, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->Status,$b->Status);
});

foreach($items as $Reader) {
    include '/extras/reader-single.php'; 
}
```

Comment: It still seems to pull all readers from the XML. Is there anything extra I can give that may help you?

Comment: I've tested it. Maybe you made a copy and paste error. However, check @pp19dd's answer. I would use his answer.

Comment: I was editing the wrong file. Well it was the right file, but an old version of it. But this does work

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to specifically query for attributes - or to exclude them.

```
$url = 'http://www.inveroak.com/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$matches = $xml->xpath( "//Reader[Pin!=4419 and Pin!=4373]" );
```

This will give you the entire structure, minus the two items # 4419 and # 4373.

Comment: Looks better than my attempt to filter them out afterwards.

Comment: by $matches do you mean this line replaces $items = array(); ?
This doesn't seem to work after I upload it, so far nothing has worked... and I'm certain everything seems okay

Comment: Pretty much. If you do `echo "<PRE>"; print_r( $matches);` you'll see an array of SimpleXMLElement objects that each have name/descr/status/etc properties.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be filter them out in the first foreach loop:

```
foreach($xml as $Reader) {
    if (array_search($Reader->Pin, $exclude) === FALSE) {
         $items[] = $Reader;
    }
}
```

In either case, you do not need:

```
$items = array_diff($items, $exclude);
```

array_diff() returns the values from the first array ($items) that do not exist in the second array ($exclude).  Because in your case the first array is an empty array, it has no values, so array_diff() will also always return an empty array.

Perhaps someone will come along with an XPath solution - that would be another approach. (EDIT - Ah, I see @pp19dd has supplied this.)